# Building visual estimate of plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**I was wondering if there were any techniques for without any kind of software, sketching 3-dimensional planes (as were taught in early algebra classes for parabolas, for example).**

I was given the following problem that was accompanied by a sketch for the area created, and I remarked that though the problem was simple with the picture, without it I would have greatly struggled, hence my question. Much thanks!

The problem (from HW: I had no issues solving it, it just underlies my motivation for creating estimates of why I want tools for estimating how planes look):

> Find the volume of the region in the 1st octant bounded by coordinate planes and the planes $$x + z = 1, \quad y + 2z = 2$$ accompanied by the below image.[image]

Comment: Do you know about the relationship between the equation of a plane and a normal direction?

Answer (score 1):

*Mathematica*:

```
 RegionPlot3D[
  x > 0 \[And] 
  y > 0 \[And] 
  z > 0 \[And] 
  x + z < 1 \[And] 
  y + 2 z < 2,
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
 BoxRatios->{1,2,1}]
```

[image]

As for its volume:

```
rr = ImplicitRegion[
  x > 0 \[And] 
  y > 0 \[And] 
  z > 0 \[And] 
  x + z < 1 \[And] 
  y + 2 z < 2, {x, y, z}];

RegionMeasure[rr]
```

(* 2/3 *)

Incidentally "3-dimensional planes" and "area created" makes no sense.  You mean "planes in three dimensions" and "volume created."

Comment: Thank you. I will be doing these problems in an exam setting so will be unable to use such software.

Comment: Then you should have stated that in your question!

Comment: Thank you! You are very right - I've marked your answer as correct. Do you think I'll have more luck editing my question or posting the re-edited version?

Comment: Edit your question.

Comment: thanks for your help. Unmarked question as resolved so I can get answers